# Retornar Dados do Banco e Listar no Combobox

Tags: php, html, banco-de-dados

Olá, gostaria de poder retornar os valores do banco da tabela empresa e para cada linha que retornar ir criando uma opção no combobox, gostaria de saber como fazer isso, eu acho que deve ser com while ou for each, mas gostaria de ajuda para montar.

Código da Comboxbox:

```
<div class="profile-info-row">
<div class="profile-info-name"> Empresa </div>  

<div class="profile-info-value">
    <select name="empresa_destino" id="form-field-1" class="col-xs-11 col-sm-6 col-md-8">
        <option value="">Selecione a Empresa</option>
        <option value="1">Emp1</option>
        <option value="2">Emp2</option>
        <option value="3">Emp3</option>
    </select>
</div>
</div>
```

Código PHP para retornar os valores do banco:

```
<?php
    session_start();

    if (!isset($_SESSION["logado"]) || $_SESSION["logado"] != TRUE) {
        header("Location: login.html");
    }

        include "conexao.php";
        include "executaSQL.php";

        $SQL = "SELECT cod_empresa , razao_social FROM `tbl_empresa`";

        $link= conectar ();
        $inserido = executaSQL($SQL, $link);

?>
```

EDIT:

Consegui ajustar esse código meu:

```
    <div class="profile-info-value">
                                        <?php
    include "conexao.php";
    include "executaSQL.php";

    $link=conectar(); 

    $busca_query = mysql_query("SELECT cod_empresa,razao_social FROM tbl_empresa")or die(mysql_error());
?>                                        
                                            <select name="empresa_destino" id="form-field-1" class="col-xs-11 col-sm-6 col-md-8">
                                                <option value="" selected disabled="disabled" hidden>Selecione a Empresa</option>

                                                <?php while ($dados = mysql_fetch_array($busca_query)) { ?>

                                            <option value="<?php echo $dados['cod_empresa']; ?>"><?php echo $dados['razao_social']; ?></option> <?php } ?>

                                            </select>
                                        </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Código da Resolução que utilizei:

```
<div class="profile-info-value">
                                        <?php
    include "conexao.php";
    include "executaSQL.php";

    $link=conectar(); 

    $busca_query = mysql_query("SELECT cod_empresa,razao_social FROM tbl_empresa")or die(mysql_error());
?>                                        
                                            <select name="empresa_destino" id="form-field-1" class="col-xs-11 col-sm-6 col-md-8">
                                                <option value="" selected disabled="disabled" hidden>Selecione a Empresa</option>

                                                <?php while ($dados = mysql_fetch_array($busca_query)) { ?>

                                            <option value="<?php echo $dados['cod_empresa']; ?>"><?php echo $dados['razao_social']; ?></option> <?php } ?>

                                            </select>
                                        </div>
```

Comment: é importante que você aprenda a usar a biblioteca padrão [PDO](https://secure.php.net/pdo) ou [mysqli](https://secure.php.net/mysqli). as funções `mysql_*` foram descontinuadas no PHP 5.5 e na versão 7.0 ela deixou de existir. Para garantir que seus programas vão funcionar em versões atualizadas do PHP , comece a migrar.

Answer (score 0):

A solução você mesmo já falou: usar alguma estrutura de *loop* (`while`, `foreach`, `for`).

Você não falou o que `executarSQL` retorna.

Assumindo que retorna um `array`, o código deve ficar assim:

```
<select name="empresa_destino" id="form-field-1" class="col-xs-11 col-sm-6 col-md-8">
    <option value="">Selecione a Empresa</option>

    <?php foreach ($inserido as $codigo => $valor): ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $codigo ?>"><?php echo $valor ?></option>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</select>
```

Consulte o guia [PHP do Jeito Certo](http://br.phptherightway.com/) e a [página de manual](https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/pdo.query.php) para aprender mais sobre o PHP moderno.